# Showing that the indeterminate $0^∞$ tends to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)=\infty$, then how can we prove: $\lim _{x→a} f(x)^{g(x)} = 0$?

I tried using logs: $\ln(\lim_{x→a} f(x)^{g(x)}=0$, then $\lim_{x→a} g(x)\ln(f(x))$.

Not quite sure where to go from here?

($f$ is a positive function)

Comment: If you can prove something like this in general, then by definition it's not an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From there you have $\log(f(x))\to_{x\to a} - \infty$ and consequently $g(x)\log(f(x))\to_{x\to a} - \infty$.

Since $f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp(g(x)\log(f(x)))$ you can conclude.

However note that this is not the best way to prove your result: you do not have an indeterminate form. Indeed "multiplying $0$ a lot of times makes always $0$".

Another way to see it would be to take $\varepsilon>0$ and to say that there exists $\eta>0$ such that for all $x \in [a-\eta,a+\eta]$, $|f(x)|\leq 1/2$ and $g(x)>\log_2(1/\varepsilon)$ (since $g$ goes to infinity). Therefore for all $x \in [a-\eta,a+\eta]$, $|f(x)^{g(x)}|\leq |f(x)|^{g(x)}\leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: "First you cannot take the $\log$ of $f$ when $f(x)<0$" Well, in general $f(x)^{g(x)}$ isn't defined then either. So that would be an issue with the original statement as well.

Comment: What does the word "exp" mean?

Comment: indeed @Arthur one has to assume that the original statement is well posed

Comment: @Jamesodare $\exp(x)=e^x$

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ then from a certain point we have $f(x)<1$ and $g(x)>1$. Then from that point we have $f(x)^{g(x)}< f(x)$. Now use that $f(x)\to 0$ again.

(Conclusion: $(\to 0^+)^{(\to+\infty)}$ is *not* an indeterminate form).

Comment: Simplest possible approach +1 and the remark at the end is very important.

Answer (score 0):

> Not quite sure where to go from here?

For starters, identify what the new terms $g(x)$ and $\ln(f(x))$ tend towards, and what you want to prove that the new limit $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ln(f(x))$ tends to. Then I would suggest to use the definition of limits directly.

Comment: g(x) still tends to Infinity and ln(f(x)) will now tend to negative infinity but how does that become equal to zero?

Comment: @Jamesodare Did you see where I said "identify [...] what you want to prove that the new limit $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ln(f(x))$ tends to"? Because if some expression tends to $0$, then its logarithm would tend to ...?